# JavaScript error, syntax ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the following JS, at some point no longer works.
from "$.each" no longer works
How can I fix? there seems to be a problem in taking the class
Can anyone help me? I can not understand where is the problem, even if I create two js file does not work ..
Html output

```
<ol id="AjaxTimeline">
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-badge primary">
        <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" rel="tooltip" title="11 hours ago via Twitter" id=""></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <div class="caption">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/2">
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-body">
            <p>Suspendisse id felis mi. Quisque blandit mattis nisl eu volutpat. Duis viverra lacus quis arcu mattis ac varius ligula convallis. Maecenas magna enim, molestie ac ultrices sed, convallis vel dolor. Vestibulum sed hendrerit massa. Integer consequat odio vitae est rutrum et egestas nibh sodales. Sed adipiscing nisl vel massa bibendum molestie.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-footer">
            <div class="voto_class" id="1">
              <div class="voto_btn">
                <div class="voto_positivo_btn">&nbsp;</div>
                <span class="voto_positivo_s">0</span>
              </div>
              <div class="voto_btn">
                <div class="voto_negativo_btn">&nbsp;</div>
                <span class="voto_negativo_s">0</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></i></a>
            <a class="pull-right">Continua a leggere</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</ol>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var base_caricamento = 0; 
var loading  = false; 
var news_caricate = 5; 

$('#AjaxTimeline').load("Caricamento_n.php", {
    'gruppo_0':base_caricamento
}, function() {
    base_caricamento++;
}); 

$(window).scroll(function() { 

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  
    {

        if(base_caricamento <= news_caricate && loading==false) 
        {
            loading = true;
            $('.caricamento_ajax').show(); 


            $.post('Caricamento_n.php',{
            'gruppo_0': base_caricamento
            }, function(data){

                $("#AjaxTimeline").append(data); 
                $('.caricamento_ajax').hide(); 

                base_caricamento++;
                loading = false; 

            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 

                alert(thrownError);
                $('.caricamento_ajax').hide();
                loading = false;

            });

        }
    }
});


$.each( $('.voto_class'), function(){
    var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");

    post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};
    $.post('Voti.php', post_data,  function(response) {
            $('#'+unique_id+' .voto_positivo_s').text(response.vote_up); 
            $('#'+unique_id+' .voto_negativo_s').text(response.vote_down);
        },'json');
});


$(".voto_class .voto_btn").click(function (e) {

    var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');
    var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 

    if(clicked_button==='voto_negativo_btn')
    {

       alert("OK");
    }
    else if(clicked_button==='voto_positivo_btn') 
    {

        alert("Error");
    }

});});
```

The problem lies in tag `<ol id="AjaxTimeline">`. I do not understand why, but if I delete the script works tag

Comment: I've seen other answers on here that imply jQuery does not like _ in selectors. Try removing the _ from your class name.

Comment: You can also try using the $(".voto_class").each() iterator instead of the generic jquery.each

Comment: The problem lies in tag " <ol id =" AjaxTimeline ">" I do not understand why, but if I delete the script works tag

Comment: Could you be more specific than "no longer works?" Do you get an error? Is it doing something you don't expect? What does happen?

Comment: @GiovanniD'ippolito Your last comment doesn't make much sense. Are you saying that if you delete the script tag, it works? Please clarify. Also, you need to explain what is meant by no longer works. What does happen, what should have happened, any error messages? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So if I delete the tag and I click on one of the loot I get the alert if the gate is not tag the alert does not appear ..

Comment: A `ul` directly inside an `ol` is not valid HTML, you need an `li` in between them

Comment: Putting an `ul` in an `ol` is invalid; I don't know if that relates to your problem or not. Are you getting an error, or is something not appearing correctly? If you're getting an error, can you post the error message?

Comment: You might wrap the `<ul>` in a `<li>` so the hierarchy is correct. You cannot just place the `<ul>` at the top layer, that forces your browser to interpret what you meant. Many times the browser will be wrong. I also suspect there is another missing tag someplace that is actually causing the issue. Commenting other layers can help pinpoint where.

Comment: @scrappedcola The only other problem with that HTML is that the `<img />` tag should be self-closing and the OP is missing the slash